# IIS Analytics and Diagnostic Logging

Tags: iis, logging, analytics, diagnostics

We have a Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5 running a small number of customer service/customer response web applications/services.

We have recently had some anecdotal feedback that some of these services are 'sometimes slow and unresponsive'.  Our own usability testing has yet to experience such problems but we have reached a point where we feel we need to be a more professional/analytical about these services and the IIS service in general.  All the sites are running application level error logging (Elmah).

Does anyone have an recommendations for an IIS monitoring/diagnostics/logging tool that would help us analyse things such as...

- user traffic profiles (pages visited, duration per page) user
- demographics (location, browser, OS)
- average/maxima/minima page load performance by page
- IIS workload

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.